# how to find the coordinates of top center of the div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a div like in below,
[image]

how can i get the (x1,y1) and (x2, y2) coordinates like in image for that div given i have top, left, bottom, right, x, y values using getBoundingClientRect() method.

i have tried something like below,

```
for x1, y1
    return {x: (rect.left + rect.width / 2), y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};

for  x2, y2
    return {x: rect.right, y:rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: does the div shown have a static width?

Comment: yes but doesnt have static height..i has min height to 62

Comment: all of the anwsers provided to those questions are not relevant to this question @SamWalpole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const circle1 = document.querySelector('#c1');
const circle2 = document.querySelector('#c2');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();

const topCenter = {
  x: rect.x + rect.width/2,
  y: rect.y,
}
const centerRight = {
  x: rect.x + rect.width,
  y: rect.y + rect.height/2,
}

const circleRadius = 5;

circle1.style.left = `${topCenter.x - circleRadius}px`;
circle1.style.top = `${topCenter.y - circleRadius}px`;

circle2.style.left = `${centerRight.x - circleRadius}px`;
circle2.style.top = `${centerRight.y - circleRadius}px`;
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box {
  --height: 100px;
  --width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - var(--width)) / 2);
  top: calc((100% - var(--height)) / 2);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" id="c1"></div>
<div class="circle" id="c2"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```